# mongodb shell: update document only if it exists

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

If I'm not mistaken `$set` in the following will add the field if it doesn't exist.

```
db.coll.update({profession:"devs"}, { $set : { daysSpent : 30 } }, {multi:true});
```

it will set `daysSpent` 30 for all docs with profession "devs" regardless of whether they have this field.

Comment: do you want to update only documents that have `daysSpent` field?

Comment: yes, that's what i want

Comment: is there selector like `$update` instead of `$set`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb update if a field does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706530/mongodb-update-if-a-field-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need yo use the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator which will match the documents that contain the field `daysSpent`

```js
db.coll.update(
    { "profession": "devs", "daysSpent": { "$exists": true }, 
    { "$set" : { "daysSpent" : 30 } }, 
    { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: so there doesn't exist a selector for updating like $update instead of $set, i dont have anything against use of $exits in query but i'm wondering